# Vlc images aquisition

Tags: vlc

someone knows what's this on VLC?

[image: vlc screenshot]

When I click on appears snapshots of ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like a translation error. What happens to those entries when you start VLC with English locale (`LC_MESSAGES=POSIX vlc`) and what is the output of `locale`?

Answer (score 0):

Those are Xserver open windows. Every opened window will appear in this list. For example if you start nautilus this new window will also appear in the list.

Those 5 windows without names are also opened windows. They belong to the Unity. If you click on one of them with the right mouse button and go to *Information* you will see the window ID:

[image: screenshot]

In order to obtain more information you can then open a terminal and type:

```
xwininfo -all -root | grep 0x3800008
```

in my case this corresponds to the unity panel:

> 0x3800008 "unity-panel": ()  1440x24+0+0  +0+0

Another four come from the Unity launcher, dash, HUD and from the login screen. You can also see this if you select one of them and click on the play button of VLC.

Comment: It does'nt work on my pc. (?) [snapshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GocCQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Today it works! :)

It's all right?

:~$ xwininfo -all -root | grep 0x3800008

```
       0x3800008 "unity-panel": ()  1366x30+0+0  +0+0
```

:~$ xwininfo -all -root | grep 0x3800002

```
       0x3800002 "XdndCollectionWindowImp": ()  1366x768+0+0  +-1466+-868
```

:~$ xwininfo -all -root | grep 0x3800005

```
       0x3800005 "unity-launcher": ()  81x738+0+0  +0+30
```

:~$ xwininfo -all -root | grep 0x380000b

```
       0x380000b "unity-dash": ()  320x200+0+0  +-420+-300
```

:~$ xwininfo -all -root | grep 0x380000c

```
       0x380000c "Hud": ()  320x200+0+0  +-420+-300
```